# Woke up my iOS app with core bluetooth

Tags: ios, swift, core-bluetooth

How to wake up my iOS app from closed state (not even in suspended or background state) with bluetooth signal (BLE). Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

**NO.**
Not Possible to open app from bluetooth signal.
You require something receive response. Which will be active if your app is Active or Background state.

Comment: If your app has been running in the past and was terminated by the OS, not by the user removing it from the app history, then it can reload on bluetooth activity. See e.g.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21812161/ios-core-bluetooth-state-preservation-and-restoration-issues?rq=1 and many other posts on state preservation.

Comment: @PhillApley the Question was to open app from Closed state by means app is not present in app history too.If app is in history means suspended then it can.

Comment: There is a difference between 'suspended in the history' and 'terminated in the history'. 'Terminated in the history' means the app must relaunch from scratch, but that it is still listed in the history. In this case the app is not running, or listening, or loaded in memory, but the operating system is listening and will launch the app if an appropriate bluetooth connection is attempted.

Comment: But indeed, if the app has never run or has been removed from the history by the user, there is, by design, no way for the app to launch without some manual user interaction, such as touching a notification alert.

Comment: That was the question exactly "wake up my iOS app from closed state (not even in suspended or background state)" closed state means not running into background as well as in history. Its Closed that set.