# Why this is happening when using CoreBluetooth?

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I made a demo iOS app by which I track nearby BLE devices, and when I get a call in this method

```
centralManager:didDiscoverPeripheral:advertisementData:RSSI
```

I create a local notification using the info of found peripheral. This is working fine when my app is in the foreground state. But Then killed the app and do nothing. All of a sudden I got a local notification while the app was not running. I read that CoreBluetooth cannot wake up iOS app from not running state. How is this possible? This occurrence is not continuous but happens sometimes.

Answer (score 3):

Core Bluetooth can wake up (even launch) an iOS app. I'm not sure who told you it couldn't. This is a very important feature. Perhaps you mean that you did not expect it to launch an app that has been force-quit? Typically that's true, but the system may or may not get around to removing your app from its observer lists. It doesn't promise you won't be relaunched after a force-quit.

Comment: So, is there any definitive way to wake up an iOS app by CoreBluetooth? Initially, I did this with remote push, but can it be replaceable by CoreBluetooth? My goal is to wake up my app by any near Bluetooth device, and then it will perform certain tasks. Anyway thanks for your reply.

Comment: I actually went through different answers like this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40671099/woke-up-my-ios-app-with-core-bluetooth), [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1962/_index.html#:~:text=A%3A%20Bluetooth%20State%20Restoration%20will,for%20pending%20Core%20Bluetooth%20requests.) and guess Core Bluetooth cannot wake up (even launch) an iOS app.

Comment: You cannot wake for *any* nearby Bluetooth device, but you can be launched if there is a device advertising a specific service you are scanning for (not nil; it has to be a specific service), or if you attempt to connect to a specific CBPeripheral before going into the background. The system will launch you when that specific device is nearby. (There is no timeout on this. The connection attempt will even survive reboots.) These are the "pending Core Bluetooth requests" that are noted in the second link. You can also be launched when advertising as a peripheral and another device connects.